# Multiple Optimal Solutions in Dynamic Programming

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming

In 2-D dynamic programming problems like Edit Distance and binary knapsack, there can be multiple optimal solutions. By tracing back from the last element in the matrix one could trace out all the possible solutions.

**Here's the question:** How to count the number of unique optimal solutions without backtracking? Is it even possible?

I've been stuck on this problem for a while. Any help would be appreciated.

Example:
The edit distance between two strings, **TREE** and **TOR** is 3.However, it has four optimal solutions.

1)
TREE
TOR_

Replace(R,O),
Replace(E,R),
Delete(E)

2)
TREE
TO_R

Replace(R,O),
Delete(E)
Replace(E,R)

3)
TREE
T_OR

Delete(R),
Replace(E,O),
Replace(E,R)

4)
T_REE
TOR__

Insert(O),
Delete(E),
Delete(E)

Comment: The answer may depend on the specific problem you are solving.  Can you pick one, and show your thoughts or your approach?  What's the context in which you encountered this question?

Comment: I've included an example. Please have a look.

Comment: Please help me see *edit distance of two strings* as a *2-D* problem.

Comment: I suggest that you narrow down the question by picking one problem (e.g., edit distance) and ask how to compute the number of optimal solutions for it, rather than asking about all problems.  Giving one example of edit distance does not address that comment because you're still asking how to do it for all dynamic programming problems.  I suggest trying to understand how to do it for a single problem (e.g., edit distance), before trying to generalize to all dynamic programming problems.

Comment: Hint: Try solving a *harder* problem -- computing the number of optimal solutions to *every* subproblem of finding the edit distance between the first $n$ characters of the first word and the first $m$ characters of the second.